# Invalid arguments for open function

Tags: python

Here is what I try to do and I use windows and Python 3.4 and PySide:

```
    def computewrite(self):
        text = self.lineID.text()
        with open(str(readdata.filename), 'a') as myfile:
            myfile.write(str(text))
```

The above codes are of course a part of a module and when I ran the module, I got an error message as follows:

```
[Errno 22] Invalid argument: '<function readdata.filename at 0x0535BF18>'
```

I am trying to write filename(readdata.filename) in string from other class, like this

```
def filename():
        filename = "inputs2.txt"
```

I have no idea how to fix the error thing as well.
I will appreciate your time and help.

Comment: You forgot the parenthses on `readdata.filename()`.  Instead of calling the function, you passed the function itself as the file name to `open`.

Comment: @Prune Nah, he didn't pass the function to `open`.

Comment: Right -- to `str`, not to `open`.

Answer (score 4):

First off, the `filename` function needs to return something.
So the body of that function would need to look like:

```
def filename():
    filename = "inputs2.txt"
    return filename
```

But the error message you are seeing is caused by trying to convert a function, `readdata.filename`, to a string. You need to call the function first to get the value:

```
open(str(readdata.filename()), 'a')
```

(note the open and close parentheses after `filename`)

If `readdata.filename` is returning a string already though, you don't need to call `str()`, and can just open the file like so:

```
open(readdata.filename(), 'a')
```

Answer (score 0):

Paul, you passed the string representation of the function to open, and that string is not a legitimate file name.  PySide is not showing us the actual Python exception, but error numbers generally come from OSError, and `import errno; errno.errorcode[22]` is `EINVAL`, which expands to invalid argument.  (Windows uses different error numbers, so you are either not using Windows or PySide is translating numbers.)  The fix is to pass a string that is at least potentially a file name.  If the file name is too long or the file is not found, you will get a different errno and message.